# how to handle the network requst in android

Tags: android, networking

I want to draw something requested online,then this is the core implement(draw logic ommitted):

```
public abstract class AbstractBasicDataHandler extends AbstractHandler{
    private DataProvider tp = new DataProvider();

    @Override
    protected void onReadyToDraw(Canvas c,int params) {
        byte[] data = tp.getDrawableData(params);
        doRender(c, data);
    }

    protected abstract void doRender(Canvas c, byte[] data);
}
```

The `AbstractBasicDataHandler` will do the job of data requesting,then any sub class of `AbstractBasicDataHandler` will only focus on the rendering work like this:

```
public class AnyClass extends AbstractBasicDataHandler{
    @Override
    doRender(Canvas c, byte[] data){
        //render according to the data
    }
}
```

However the question is the data requesting is a time-consumed work which means that the data may noe returned immedirately.

So any experience to meet this kind of requirements?

Comment: AsyncTasks in an Activity, Loaders in a fragment. This topic has been covered in depth many times.

Comment: executor for long running operations http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html. If not long running asycntask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can use `Asynctask` to perform its network operation in its `doInBackground()` and perform your UI operation in its `postExecute()`.